# why doesn't fillcolor work with graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I am following the exact instructions from the graphviz documentation, but I am unable to add fillcolor to nodes.

Here is my graph:

```
digraph hello_world {
 node [href="javascript:void(click_node('\N'))"]
 node0 [label="No label",shape=box,width=0.75,height=0.75,fixedsize=true]
 node1 [label="No label",shape=box,width=0.75,height=0.75,fixedsize=true]
 node2 [label="No label",shape=box,width=0.75,height=0.75,fixedsize=true]
 node3 [label="No label",shape=box,width=0.75,height=0.75,fixedsize=true]
 nodeEdge0 [fixedsize=true,shape=diamond,label=".Nojjjj label.",fillcolor=red]
 node3 -> nodeEdge0 [arrowhead=none]
 nodeEdge0 -> node2
}
```

Still, the graph does not set `nodeEdge0` to have a red background color.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

add style=filled to the node

```
nodeEdge0 [fixedsize=true,shape=diamond,label=".Nojjjj label.",fillcolor=red, style=filled]
```

Comment: if there is already `fillcolor`, why is `style=filled` still needed?

Comment: [Because the documentation says so](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fillcolor/). But yes, I would also prefer a different default.